# Chrome Back button is not preserving the url history when using Ajax for pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

pls help me out. i recent used ajax for my laravel pagination. Whenever i click he back button. it does not go back to the page i am coming from. it goes back to page 1. let me Illustrate this clearly.
(1) i have a list of items paginated with jquery ajax.
(2) when i visit the 5th page( for example) and click an item to view details of that item and decided to click the browser back button, i am expected to be taken back to page 5 where i was. instead, i am taken back to page 1.
(3) This is only happening in chrome related browsers. it works well in Firefox;

//BELOW IS MY AJAX CODE;

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(document).on('click','.pagination a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageNumber = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
    getMorePage(pageNumber)
});

function getMorePage(page) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/all-products-ajax/"+"?page="+page,
        type: "get",
        datatype: "html"
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#product-view').html(data); 
    }).fail(function () {
        alert('Posts could not be loaded.');
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax queries are different than browsing a webpage. You may need to register new routes to browser's history.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

You might want to check out here.

Answer (score 0):

In an HTML document, the history.pushState() method adds an entry to the browser's session history stack.

****->** window.history.pushState("", "", url);**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(document).on('click','.pagination a',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var pageNumber = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
        getMorePage(pageNumber)

        // Add this line
        window.history.pushState("", "", url);
    })
    
    function getMorePage(page) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/all-products-ajax/"+"?page="+page,
            type: "get",
            datatype: "html"
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#product-view').html(data); 
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('Posts could not be loaded.');
       });
});
```